# Coldfusion 9 default timezone issue

Tags: coldfusion, jvm, timezone

When I execute getDefault() on a java.util.TimeZone object created from ColdFusion 9 I am getting "Pakistan Time".  We are in the eastern timezone and our server (Windows 2003) is reporting proper timezone.  Where would ColdFusions JVM be getting this timezone?

TimeZone: Pakistan Time (Asia/Karachi)

Comment: Actually mine came with GMT and was listed as: `-Duser.timezone=GMT`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<strike>try this: http://troymurray.blogspot.com/2007/12/coldfusion-timezone-change.html</strike>(deleted)

Content retrieved from [Google's cache](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3aHfCGuAYTRS4J%3atalltroym.blogspot.com/2007/12/coldfusion-timezone-change.html%20&cd=9&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=pl):

> ## ColdFusion Timezone Change
>
> So I've been working on a component to accept data from whatever and insert it into our Oracle database, no big deal.  But, I need to do this with date and times, which gets really sticky with Oracle.  I noticed however that my ColdFusion function Now() was returning the wrong time, about 5 hours off, which corresponds to my timezone (-5).
>   I looked all through the ColdFusion Admin but wasn't able to find anywhere to specify this.  I then seem to remember that when I setup this server, and installed ColdFusion on it, that I had the wrong timezone set and somehow that must have been saved.  Since ColdFusion relies on Java I needed to change the time zone with the Java Virtual Machine (JVM) that ColdFusion runs.  Here is how I did it:
>
> 1. First, find the correct timezone ID for your location.  I found mine by going [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r0/topic/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/info/aes/ae/rrun_svr_timezones.html).
> 2. Login to the ColdFusion Admin
> 3. Under Server Settings go to Java and JVM
> 4. Locate the JVM Arguments textarea
> 5. Add a space after the last character, then "-Duser.timezone=" and then your [timezone ID](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r0/topic/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/info/aes/ae/rrun_svr_timezones.html).
> 6. Click the "Submit Changes" button
> 7. Restart the "ColdFusion 8 Application Server" service
> 8. Verify your time shows correctly now.

Comment: Thanks, I'm still curious as to why the default would be a different zone.

Comment: Maybe because they hardcoded something, CF9 was written in India so... :D

Comment: This blog has been removed, does anyone have a copy of the instructions?

Comment: Google's cache: http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:HfCGuAYTRS4J:talltroym.blogspot.com/2007/12/coldfusion-timezone-change.html+&cd=9&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=pl